# How to unit test (using Jasmine) a function in a controller which calls a factory service which returns a promise

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angularjs-factory, angular-mock

In the below ***SampleController***, how do I unit test that ***postAttributes*** function calls ***sampleService.updateMethod***. I'm having trouble since the updateMethod returns promise.

```
    angular.module('sampleModule')
       .controller('SampleController', SampleController);

    SampleController.$inject =['sampleService'];

    function SampleController(sampleService){

    this.postAttributes = function() {    
        sampleService.updateMethod(number,attributes)
            .then(function(response){
                //do something on successful update
            },function(response){
                //do something on unsuccessful update
            });
        }; 

    }
```

Here is the factory service that I have:

```
    angular.module('sampleModule')
        .factory('sampleService', sampleService);

    sampleService.$inject = ['$http'];

    function sampleService($http) {
        return {
            getMethod: function(acctNumber){
                return $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: //api endpoint
                });
            },
            updateMethod: function(number, attributes){
                return $http({
                    method: 'PUT',
                    url: //api endpoint,
                    data: //payload
                });
            }
        };
    }
```

I would like to mock the factory service in the controller spec rather than injecting the actual service directly into $controller, since most of unit testing guidelines specify to test a unit under isolation.

Sample controller spec:

```
    describe('SampleController Test', function(){
        var $controller;
        var service;

        beforeEach(angular.mock.module('sampleModule')); 

        beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(_$controller_){
            $controller = _$controller_;
        }));

        it('Testing $scope variable', function(){
            var sampleController = $controller('SampleController', { 
                sampleService: service, //mocked factory service 
            });

            sampleController.postAttributes(); //calling the function first
            //here I would like to make an assertion to check if
            //sampleService.updateMethod has been called with certain parameters                        
            //how do I do that??
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googled around and found a solution to mock the factory service and followed promise creation approach like @TehBeardedOne and made it to return it from the mocked service.

```
    describe('SampleController', function(){

        var mockService, controller, deferred, $rootScope;

        beforeEach(function(){

            angular.mock.module('sampleModule');

            angular.mock.module(function($provide){
                $provide.factory('sampleService', function($q){
                    function updateMethod(acct, attr){
                        deferred = $q.defer();
                        return deferred.promise;
                    }
                    return{updateMethod: updateMethod};
                });
            });

            angular.mock.inject(function($controller, sampleService, _$rootScope_){
                $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
                mockService = sampleService;
                spyOn(mockService, 'updateMethod').and.callThrough();
                controller =$controller('SampleController', {
                    sampleService: mockService,
                })
            });
        });

        it('postAttributes function should call updateMethod', function(){

            controller.postAttributes();
            expect(mockService.updateMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(mockService.updateMethod).toHaveBeenCalledWith(controller.accountNumber, controller.attributes);
        });

        it('postAttributes success block', function(){
            controller.postAttributes();
            var res = {
                data: '2323'
            }
            deferred.resolve(res);
            $rootScope.$digest();
            expect(//something in success block).toBe(something);
        });

        it('postAttributes failure block', function(){
            controller.postAttributes();
            var res = {
                data: '9898'
            }
            deferred.reject(res);
            $rootScope.$digest();
            expect(controller.lame).toBe('dont type shit');
        });

    });
```

I've mocked the ***sampleService*** with **$provider** service and made ***updateMethod*** to return a promise using **$q**. Later on you can resolve or reject the promise and test the success and failure blocks in individual it blocks.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a spy to check that the function is being called. There are several ways to go about doing this as I'm sure you have probably already noticed. You also need to inject `$q` and `$rootScope` as you will need to loop the digest cycle in order to return the promise.

In fact, if all you want to do is check that the function is being called a simple spy will work just fine. You don't even have to return the promise. That being said, if you want to continue on through the `postAttributes()` function and test other stuff inside this function then you will need to return the promise to do that. Here is the approach that works well for me. Something like this should work.

```
describe('SampleController Test', function(){
    var $controller;
    var service;
    var $q;
    var $rootScope;
    var updateMethodDeferred;
    var ctrl;
    var mockHttpObject;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('sampleModule'));

    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(_sampleService_, _$q_, _$rootScope_, _$controller_){
        service = _sampleService_;
        $q = _$q_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $controller = _$controller_;

        mockHttpObject = {
            //add mock properties here
        }

        updateMethodDeferred = $q.defer();
        spyOn(service, 'updateMethod').and.returnValue(updateMethodDeferred.promise);

        ctrl = $controller('SampleController', {
            sampleService: service, //mocked factory service
        });
    }));

    it('Testing $scope variable', function(){
        ctrl.postAttributes();
        expect(service.updateMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('Should do something after promise is returned', function(){
        ctrl.postAttributes();
        updateMethodDeferred.resolve(mockHttpObject);
        $rootScope.$digest();
        expect(/*something that happened on successful update*/).toBe(/*blah*/)           
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried the above approach but later found out that **sampleService** by itself has lot of dependencies. So if I've to follow above approach then I need to inject all the dependencies of the sampleService as well, which should be the case since we are testing just controller we should mock all the dependencies. Currently I'm trying to mock the service with $provide.factory. How do I return promise from the mocked service with both success and error blocks?!

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to inject the dependencies for the service as well. I have never had to do that and some of my service also have several dependencies. In any case you can use deferred.resolve() to hit your success block and deferred.reject() to hit your error block.